# URLSearchParams With Fetch In EdgeHTML 17

Tags: fetch-api, microsoft-edge

I am having trouble posting form data using URLSearchParams in EdgeHTML 17 only. Does anyone know of any issues with the latest update?

I am using the following NPM packages as polyfills for older browsers:

1. whatwg-fetch: "2.0.4"
2. promise-polyfill: "8.0.0"
3. url-search-params-polyfill: "4.0.0"

Here is the code that I am using:

```
fetch("/api/checkout", { method: 'POST', headers: new Headers({
        "X-Requested-With": "FetchAPI",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
}), credentials: 'include', body: new URLSearchParams($("#MyForm").serialize()) })
.then((msg) => {
    return msg.json();
}).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that edge doesn't automatically does a toString anymore on the body. By adding `.toString()` to the body it should work.